# How to properly play audio file using just_audio - flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, just-audio

Am working on a music app were am suppose to stream audio and also play my locally stored files.

Am using flutter and am not good on it, Actually am learning.

What i wanted is to be helped on how i can play a file properly, The intention is to play a file once provided to the player path. bellow is my code.

```
import 'package:myApp/shared/MusicProgressIndicator.dart';
import 'package:myApp/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:myApp/app.dart';

class SingleSongScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "SingleSongScreen";
  static var song = {};
  SingleSongScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SingleSongScreenState createState() => _SingleSongScreenState();
}

class _SingleSongScreenState extends State<SingleSongScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Duration currentDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 1000);
  bool showRemaining = false;
  AnimationController controller;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    controller.repeat(reverse: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final player  = AudioPlayer();
    var song      = SingleSongScreen.song;
    var songPath  = app.base+"play.php?file="+song['song'];
    print(song);
    print(songPath);
    
    player.stop();
    player.setUrl(songPath).then((play){
       player.play();
      print("Playing now");
    });

    return Window(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      header: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            IconicButton(
              icon: backIcon,
              iconColor: Colors.grey,
              transparent: true,
              circledIcon: false,
              size: 40,
              onClicked: () {
                goBack(context);
              },
            ),
            Favicon(onClicked: () {
              goto(page: MainScreen.id, context: context);
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: [
        VerticalSpacer(
          h: 20,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 250,
          child: Carousel(
            boxFit: BoxFit.contain,
            autoplay: carouselAutoPlay,
            animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
            dotSize: 6.0,
            dotIncreasedColor: Color(0xFF33A3FF),
            dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
            dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
            dotVerticalPadding: 10.0,
            showIndicator: true,
            indicatorBgPadding: 7.0,
            images: images(),
          ),
        )
      ],
      footer: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Marquee(
                child: Label(
                  song['title'],
                  bold: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Marquee(
                child: Label(
                  song['artist'],
                  bold: true,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            // ACTION ICONS SECTION
            VerticalSpacer(
              h: 25,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  VerticalIconicButton(
                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.fileDownload,
                    label: "Download",
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    textColor: Colors.grey,
                    scale: 1.2,
                    onClicked: (){
                      var downloadURL = songPath.replaceAll("play.php", "download.php");
                      app app2 = new app();
                      toast("Downloading a file "+song['song']);
                      app2.fetchServer({'method':'download','file':song['song']}).then((fileInfo){
                        if(fileInfo['status']=="success"){
                          toast("Download complete "+song['song']);
                          app2.saveDownload(song['song'],song['artist'],fileInfo['file']);
                        }else{
                          toast("There was an error while downloading a file");
                        }
                        print("downloaded file is");
                        print(fileInfo);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  VerticalIconicButton(
                    icon: Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                    label: "Favourite",
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    textColor: Colors.grey,
                    scale: 1.2,
                  ),
                  VerticalIconicButton(
                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.readme,
                    label: "Lyrics",
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    textColor: Colors.grey,
                    scale: 1.2,
                    onClicked: () {
                      goto(page: LyricsScreen.id, context: context, args: lyric);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // SONG PLAY PROGRESS INDICATOR
            VerticalSpacer(),
            MusicProgressIndicator(
              progress: currentDuration,
              buffered: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
              total: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
              showTotalRemainingTime: showRemaining,
              onSeek: (duration) {
                setState(() {
                  currentDuration = duration;
                  showRemaining = !showRemaining;
                });
                // _player.seek(duration);
              },
            ),

            // MUSIC PLAY CONTROLLER ACTION BUTTON

            VerticalSpacer(
              h: 20,
            ),

            Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  IconicButton(
                    icon: Icons.repeat_one,
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    transparent: true,
                    circledIcon: false,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: IconicButton(
                              icon: Icons.skip_previous_rounded,
                              iconColor: Colors.white,
                              transparent: true,
                              circledIcon: false,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 15),
                        IconicButton(
                          icon: Icons.pause,
                          iconColor: Colors.grey,
                          iconCircleColor: Colors.blue,
                          size: 50,
                          onClicked: (){
                            toast("Playing file");
                            player.stop();
                            player.setUrl(songPath).then((play){
                              player.play();
                              print("Playing now");
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 15,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: IconicButton(
                              icon: Icons.skip_next_rounded,
                              iconColor: Colors.white,
                              transparent: true,
                              circledIcon: false,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconicButton(
                    icon: Icons.queue_music_outlined,
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    transparent: true,
                    circledIcon: false,
                    size: 50,
                    onClicked: () {
                      goto(page: AllSongsScreen.id, context: context);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // BOTTTOM SPACE
            VerticalSpacer(
              h: 30,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void toast(String message){
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content:  Text(message.toString()),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'OK',
        onPressed: () { },
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

The code which i have used to play sound, is producing

1. Annoying sound, something a double sounds or waves crossing
2. It's allowing playing of multiple sounds.

Note: I purchased the template.

Thanks, Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have called the `setState()` method in the `addListener` of `controller` and directly called the `player.stop()` and `player.play()` methods inside the widget build.

Before calling the stop or play methods, check whether the player is not null and is not playing

```dart
if(player.playing){

}
```

And you should not initialize your player inside the widget build. It is not advisable.

Comment: Thank's @Suganya, I wish i could learn from your possible sample. am beginner.

Comment: Try to use viewmodel (MVVM) structure to handle audio player. It will make your work simple and you can handle audio player more effectively

Comment: Thanks, I moved the final player  = AudioPlayer(); outside the  Widget build(BuildContext context); It has worked.

The problem is still playing multiple files at same time and player.isPlaying its not method

Comment: Try to add unique I'd for player and check

Answer (score 1):

For avoid playing multiple audios simultaneously, maybe you need think about  making the AudioPlayer a SINGLETON. The code above show me that every time you enter that page, there will be a new AudioPlayer created associate with and you are not dispose it on dispose(). Here's some code I wrote for my flutter podcast open source project.
[a podcast case using just audio package](https://github.com/fengwensheng/flutter_agora)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30169191)